# Удаление ячейки с определенным значением

Tags: javascript, html

Как удалить ячейку со значением 3?

```
   <table id="history">
        <tr class="row">
            <th class="nyr">SteamID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cellHis">1</td>
            <td class="cellHid">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cellHis">3</td>
            <td class="cellHid">4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так. Просто надо взять элементы с классом `cellHis`. Циклом пройтись по ним. и если текст ровно `3` то удалить текущий.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.cellHis').each(function( index ) {
    if($( this ).text() == '3'){
      $( this ).remove();
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="history">
    <tr class="row">
        <th class="nyr">SteamID</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cellHis">1</td>
        <td class="cellHid">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cellHis">3</td>
        <td class="cellHid">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Тогда через `.filter()`.

```js
$("#history .row td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "3";
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="history">
    <tr class="row">
        <th class="nyr">SteamID</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cellHis">1</td>
        <td class="cellHid">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cellHis">3</td>
        <td class="cellHid">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так пойдет ?

```js
$("#history .row").find("td:contains('3')").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="history">
        <tr class="row">
            <th class="nyr">SteamID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cellHis">1</td>
            <td class="cellHid">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cellHis">3</td>
            <td class="cellHid">4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: А если значение храниться в переменной? Могу ли я так обратиться `$("#history .row").find("td:contains(${id})").remove();` ?

Comment: @klifort `contains('3')` -  нельзя так.... внутри может быть написано `привет3раза` и эта ячейка удалится

Comment: @MegaRoks переменную можно, но данный ответ неверен. птчт ↑

Comment: Ответ написан так как и подан вопрос. Возможно не все возможности и охватывает, но решает ту задачу которая написана

Comment: @klifort в вопросе вполне ясно написано что `со значением 3`, а не `содержащее значение 3`